# AngularCli - Can't bind to 'textMask' during test

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, text-mask

I'm using `textMask` node module to format the input tags for my form. I followed all instructions in the Git repository and the module woks perfectly. But when I try to run the component test it says: `Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'textMask' since isn't a known property.`. Why I have this issue? This is my HTML template:

```html
 <input [textMask]="{mask: cpfMask}" type="text" id="inputCpf" required pattern="^[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}$" name="inputCpf" [(ngModel)]="user.identification.value" #inputCpf="ngModel">
```

This is my **user.component.ts**:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css'],
  providers: [RegisterUserService, TokenManagerService]
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  private user: User;
  private error: string;
  private id: string;
  private credential: Credential;
  public cpfMask = [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '.', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '.', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/];
```

And this is my **app.module.ts:**

```ts
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    TextMaskModule,
    ...
```

I already visited the other few topics in SO that talk about this issue but their solutions didn't solved my problem.

Topic 1: [text-mask is not working for angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188588/text-mask-is-not-working-for-angular-2)

Topic 2: [Can't bind to 'x' since it isn't a known property of 'input' Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022548/cant-bind-to-x-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input-angular-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take is that [as in this guide](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/directives/), it is a malconfigured test issue. You want to configure your testing environment according to be able to use external directives.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific, please?

Comment: The problem exists as the required module is not imported. Maybe a different version is imported, or some new version lacks the said directive probably. Other than that, I am sorry, this answer is quite old to be sure what was the problem here :\

Comment: Alright, thanks for taking the time to answer though .

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the module TextMask. Working in my Approach.

```
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';
```

/../

```
imports: [ ... 

  TextMaskModule,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue even when the module was imported in `TestBed`. Later I noticed this issue reproduced only locally but tests passed on CI. To fix this locally you need to drop and install `node_modules` again